# Why does this parser do-block fail?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand do-blocks/sequencing actions, parsers and monads.

```
newtype Parser a = P ( String -> [ ( a, String ) ] )

item :: Parser Char
item = P (\inp -> case inp of
             []     -> []
             (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)])

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse (P p) inp = p inp

firstThird :: Parser (Char,Char)
firstThird = do x <- item
                item
                y <- item
                return (x,y)
```

I don't understand why

```
parse firstThird "ab"
```

evaluates to

```
[]
```

Why is it when one of the actions fail the whole do-block fails?

Comment: Is `!` supposed to be `->`? Please stick to standard ASCII notation.

Comment: What would you expect it to evaluate to instead? `[(('a', ???), "")]` - what should go in place of the `???` there?

Comment: Yes `!` was `->` that was a formatting error. It still doesn't explain why `[]` is returned as the actual result.

Comment: How is your `Monad` instance defined?

Comment: If you return a `[]`, then it means there are no options anymore to parse the content. The idea is that you here implement a parser than can perform "backtracking". You thus map a string to a list of "candidates", each candidate yields a result, and the rest of the string ot parse. By combining multiple parsers, you can parse more complicated strings.

Comment: The instances can be derived! `newtype Parser a = P .. deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState String) via StateT String []` https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia

Comment: You ask the question “list all ways to take the first 3 characters of this string” and give it a string with 2 characters. The only valid answer is “there are no ways to take three characters from a list of two characters” and thus it gives you an empty list of results.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included a `Monad` instance for your `Parser`, but a standard one might be given by:

```
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap = liftM
instance Applicative Parser where
  pure x = P $ \str -> [(x, str)]
  (<*>) = ap
instance Monad Parser where
  P p >>= f = P $ \str ->
    [result | (x, rest) <- p str, let P q = f x, result <- q rest]
```

With this instance, I can duplicate your result, and the parser is operating as intended.  Usually a monadic parser is designed so that when a sequence of parsers is bound together (using the `>>=` operator, or as multiple steps in do-block notation), the **intended** meaning is that each parser is tried in sequence and must "succeed" in order for the entire sequence to be successful.

In your case, "success" is defined as a parser returning a non-empty list of possible parses.  In order for `firstThird` to return a non-empty list, each of the three `item` parsers, in sequence, must produce a non-empty list.  For the input string `"ab"`, the first call to `item` produces the non-empty list `[('a',"b")]`, the second call to `item` produces the non-empty list `[('b',"")]`, and the third call to `item` has nothing left to parse and so returns the empty list `[]`.  No other parse is possible.

If you want to allow a parser to fail but continue the parse, you can use a combinator.  There's a standard one named `optional` in `Control.Applicative`.
To use it, you'd need an `Alternative` instance for your `Parser`:

```
instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = P $ \_ -> []
  P p <|> P q = P $ \str -> p str ++ q str
instance MonadPlus Parser
```

and then you can write:

```
firstThird :: Parser (Char,Char)
firstThird = do x <- item
                optional item
                y <- item
                return (x,y)
```

which allows:

```
> parse firstThird "ab"
[(('a','b'),"")]
> parse firstThird "abc"
[(('a','c'),""),(('a','b'),"c")]
```

Note that `"abc"` can be parsed two ways with `firstThird`, with and without skipping parsing for the middle `item`.

This is the usual way of writing monadic parsers:  the `Monad` is used for a sequence of parses, all of which must succeed, while the separate `Alternative` (AKA `MonadPlus`) instance and the `<|>` operator in particular are used to gracefully handle cases where parsers are allowed to fail and allow other parsers to be tried instead.